# Omit empty elements from XSLT 1.0 output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transform

I'm using XSLT 1.0 to transform an XML document to a different schema of XML. The source document may or may not have elements depending on the source database it is built from.

EG

```
   <Patients>
        <Patient id="1019">
            <Surname>Acqua</Surname>
            <Forenames>Matthew James</Forenames>
            <VoicePhone>0111 222 33333</VoicePhone>
        </Patient>
        <Patient id="1020">
            <Surname>Red</Surname>
            <Forenames>James Alan</Forenames>
        </Patient>
    </Patients>
```

The resulting output after transforming via XML will have empty elements in it because the VoicePhone in the second patient doesn't exist (rather than exist but is empty).

The XSLT is along these lines:

```
<xsl:template match="//Patients/Patient">
<PatientRxs>
  <PatientInfo>
    <FirstName>
      <xsl:value-of select="Forenames"/>
    </FirstName>
    <Telephone>
      <xsl:value-of select="VoicePhone"/>
    </Telephone>
  </PatientInfo>
</PatientRxs>
</xsl:template>
```

And I end up with:

```
<PatientRxs>
    <PatientInfo>
        <FirstName>Matthew James</FirstName>
        <Telephone>0111 222 33333</Telephone>
    </PatientInfo>
</PatientRxs>
<PatientRxs>
    <PatientInfo>
        <FirstName>James Alan</FirstName>
        <Telephone/>
    </PatientInfo>
</PatientRxs>
```

Where I actually want:

```
<PatientRxs>
    <PatientInfo>
        <FirstName>Matthew James</FirstName>
        <Telephone>0111 222 33333</Telephone>
    </PatientInfo>
</PatientRxs>
<PatientRxs>
    <PatientInfo>
        <FirstName>James Alan</FirstName>
    </PatientInfo>
</PatientRxs>
```

Although I could test if the value exists this is just 1 of hundreds of elements that could potentially not exist in the source document and would like to avoid having an XSLT sheet testing every single one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a generic template that matches any element, but takes a parameter to allow that element to be renamed

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="//Patients/Patient">
    <PatientRxs>
      <PatientInfo>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Forenames" mode="field">
          <xsl:with-param name="newName" select="'FirstName'" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="VoicePhone" mode="field">
          <xsl:with-param name="newName" select="'Telephone'" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </PatientInfo>
    </PatientRxs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="field">
      <xsl:param name="newName" select="local-name()" />

      <xsl:element name="{$newName}">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, if the element being matched does not exist, nothing gets output for that element at all.

Comment: I was hoping someone knew of a nice little line to put at the head of the XSLT but this works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Patients">
        <xsl:element name="PatientRxs">
            <xsl:for-each select="Patient">
                <xsl:element name="PatientInfo">
                    <xsl:element name="Forenames">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Forenames"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:if test="VoicePhone">
                        <xsl:element name="Telephone">
                            <xsl:value-of select="VoicePhone"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
Test if Voicephone exist then insert element otherwise not.
```

Comment: if element 'Voicephone' is empty then your code will create empty telephone.

Comment: Thanks for your input but as I said in the original question this is just a sample of what could be hundreds of possible empty elements and I didn't want to test them all as it would make for messing Xslt.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Patients">
        <xsl:element name="PatientRxs">
            <xsl:for-each select="Patient">
                <xsl:element name="PatientInfo">
                    <xsl:element name="Forenames">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Forenames"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="VoicePhone"/>
                        </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="VoicePhone">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="text()">
                <xsl:element name="Telephone">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="empty(.)"/>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
```

Try this one